# Relation already exists while deploying to Heroku

Tags: asp.net-core, heroku, relational-database, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy my APIs (using ASP .NET Core) to Heroku but it returns this error while deploying: "relation Users already exists".
Can anyone show me where did I do wrong?
Thanks in advance

Here's my migration code and the error I got:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Users",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uuid", nullable: false),
                Username = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: true),
                Password = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: true),
                FirstName = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: true),
                LastName = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: true),
                BirthDay = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "timestamp without time zone", nullable: false),
                Phone = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: true),
                Role = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_User", x => x.Id);
            });

        migrationBuilder.InsertData(
            table: "Users",
            columns: new[] { "Id", "BirthDay", "FirstName", "LastName", "Password", "Phone", "Role", "Username" },
            values: new object[] { new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001"), new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified), "Admin", "01", "d34b21af1ebb547742f2a78124c73764", null, 2, "admin" });
    }
```

ERROR HERE:

CREATE TABLE "Users" (
2021-11-25T17:00:20.844160+00:00 app[web.1]: "Id" uuid NOT NULL,

2021-11-25T17:00:20.844164+00:00 app[web.1]: "Username" text NULL,

2021-11-25T17:00:20.844164+00:00 app[web.1]: "Password" text NULL,

2021-11-25T17:00:20.844164+00:00 app[web.1]: "FirstName" text NULL,

2021-11-25T17:00:20.844164+00:00 app[web.1]: "LastName" text NULL,

2021-11-25T17:00:20.844165+00:00 app[web.1]: "BirthDay" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,

2021-11-25T17:00:20.844165+00:00 app[web.1]: "Phone" text NULL,

2021-11-25T17:00:20.844165+00:00 app[web.1]: "Role" integer NOT NULL,

2021-11-25T17:00:20.844165+00:00 app[web.1]: CONSTRAINT "PK_User" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")

2021-11-25T17:00:20.844166+00:00 app[web.1]: );

2021-11-25T17:00:20.857104+00:00 app[web.1]: Unhandled exception. Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42P07: relation "Users" already exists

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved this problem. This error is caused by auto migrating database. Just drop the table and re-deploying the app on heroku.